# What can go wrong when allowing file uploads on a web server?

Tags: webserver, file-upload

Some basics that are self-evident:

- Infected/harmful file can be uploaded for other users to download
- A bug in the web-site's code allowing code execution, thus allowing execution of the uploaded file on the web-server itself
- DoS (ofcourse, but that's also possible without uploads)

But what else?

Comment: Please have a look at OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

Comment: Copyright, privacy and other legal issues relating to disclosure of private information. Liability for publishing indecent or libelous content.